# Causing a redirect loop, can't figure out why or a better way to achive the same goal

Tags: php, redirect

Im trying to make a cart page, simple but im causing a redirect loop and can't figure out why.

what im trying to do:
make items sent to cart.php as cart.php?item={id}
Send them to login if they are not already logged in, but temporarily save what they are trying to add so it can be complete once they login.

It then checks for a cart, if no cart exists it should make one and resend the request again.
if they have a cart, it should add the item to `1_cart_items`.

what is happening?
A redirect loop is happening, and the cart is being made with each redirect. Noting that idealy a user should only have 1 active cart at a time.
(Note that the redirect loop only happens when logged in, and when the query string ?item={id} is sent.

```
<?php
include 'globals.php';
global $dbh;
//include 'member_func.php';
$vartomatch = hash('sha1', "{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}");
if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {
if ($_GET['item']) {
    $_SESSION['active_cart_item'] = $_GET['item'];
}
header("location: login.php");
exit;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['active_cart_item'])) {
$adding = $_SESSION['active_cart_item'];
unset($_SESSION['active_cart_item']);
header("location: cart.php?item=$adding");
}
else if ($_SESSION['ip'] !== $vartomatch) {
header("location: account.php?act=logout");
}
else {
$userid = $_SESSION['user'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `1_members` WHERE id=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$ir = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
if (isset($_GET['item'])) {
// item set, see if they have active cart to add item too...
if (isset($_SESSION['active_cart'])) {
    // they do. check db for cart.
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `1_cart` WHERE `belongs_to`=? AND `complete`=?");
    $cartid = $_SESSION['active_cart'];
    $stmt->bindValue(1,$cartid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(2,'0',PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
        //Got thier cart. Now Check it is thiers.
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($row['belongs_to'] !== $_SESSION['user']) {
            die('hack attempt');
        }
        // good stuff, now we are ready for the item id. 
        //Should we set a session variable to identify cart or just do db the normal way?
        $itmid = $_GET['item'];
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `3_types` WHERE `id`=?");
        $stmt->bindValue(1,$itmid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        if (!$stmt->rowCount()) {
            echo  '
            Sorry you are trying to add an item that does not exist or that has been deleted 
            and is no longer in existance.';
            exit;
            die('<br /> See above.');
        }

        $r=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $thiscart = $_SESSION['active_cart'];
        $serv_name = $r['serv_name'];
        $serv_title = $r['serv_title'];
        $serv_price = $r['serv_price'];
        $warranty_type = $r['warranty_type'];
        $image = $r['image'];
        $turn_around = $r['turn_around'];

                    // should this be in a while loop when we only expect 1 result?
                    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INERT INTO `1_cart_items` (`origid`,`forid`, `name`, `title`, `price`, `warranty`, `image`, `turn_around`)
                     VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    $stmt->bindValue(1,$itmid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(2,$thiscart,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(3,$serv_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(4,$serv_title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(5,$serv_price,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(6,$warranty_type,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(7,$image,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(8,$turn_around,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->execute();
                   header ("location: cart.php");

    }
    else {
        // THE SESSION VARIABLE LIED! THEY DON'T GOT A CART!!!!!
        unset($_SESSION['active_cart']);
        // reload the page...
        // make them send the same get request.
        header ("location: cart.php?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}");
    }
}
else {
// make a cart for them.
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `1_cart` (`belongs_to`, `complete`) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2,'0',PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$_SESSION['active_cart'] == $userid;
header("location: cart.php?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}");
}
 }
```

1: What is causing the redirect loop?

2: Have I done this the long way / any cleanups to suggest?

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all to see where your code path varies from what is expected?

Comment: Yes, but as I can figure. the `if (isset($_SESSION['active_cart']))` at the start, must be false for some reason, yet in the else for that if, I make the cart and set `$_SESSION['active_cart']` to thier userid. That would mean active_cart is set. `var_dump($_SESSION)` would imply active cart isn't getting set. yet `$_SESSION['active_cart'] == $userid;` is valid code, and on the line before where `$userid` is used, its correct in the database.

Comment: Hang on. Am I that stupid... my problem is the `==` when setting a variable correct?

Answer (score 0):

Right at the top of your code after your first and second if you just redirect, perhaps you forgot your else?

```
if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {
   if ($_GET['item']) {
      $_SESSION['active_cart_item'] = $_GET['item'];
   } else {
      header("location: login.php");
      exit;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['item'])) {
    // item set, see if they have active cart to add item too...
    ...
    ...
    header("location: cart.php?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}");
}
```

So each time you are in `?item=x` your script will redirect to `?item=x` until forever, because every time you visited `http://example.com?item=x` your QUERY_STRING will be `item=x` and `$_GET['item']` will be set

Comment: My redirect loop was being caused by `$_SESSION['active_cart'] == $userid;` changing to `$_SESSION['active_cart'] = $userid;` Solved the problem, The simple errors are always the easiest to miss!